# Round Counter using Get and Set C#

Tags: c#

Im using Get; and Set; im trying to make a round counter when user inputs Rounds, Minutes, and seconds. Ive managed to create the buttons and input using Get; Set; ... the problem is when the time reaches 0 for minutes and seconds it doesnt reset the minutes and seconds to the original value the user entered the first time, it just keeps it at 0.... Please help.. I didnt add the button or timer start code that all works just the get set problem

```
class User
    {
        public static int Rounds { get; set; } 
        public static int InputRounds { get; set; }
        public static int Sec { get; set; }
        public static int Min { get; set; }

}
  private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){

      User.sec--;
      if(User.sec <= 0) 
       {
         User.Min--;
       }
      if(User.Min <= 0) 
       {
         User.Rounds++;
       }
      if(User.Rounds >= User.InputRounds) // User.Input is the first value the user input 
       {
         User.Min = ????; // This is my problem with the question marks
         User.Sec = ????; // Im trying to set the value back to the users value entered
         User.Rounds++;   // then add 1 round
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, thank you for you contribution but, why not to use another set of variables like User.OriginalMin, User.OriginalSec ? or something inside the user class called something like ResetOriginalTime() -> and that would take care of restoring the original values ....

Comment: Why do you need static properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to refactor your User class, and please don't use static properties unless necessary.

```
public class User
{
    private int oMin;
    private int oSec;

    public User(int min, int sec, int maxRounds)
    {
        Min = min;
        oMin = min; // Saving Original Values

        Sec = sec;
        oSec = sec; // Saving Original Values

        MaxRounds = maxRounds;
    }

    public int Rounds { get; private set; }
    public int MaxRounds { get; }
    public int Sec { get; private set; }
    public int Min { get; private set; }

    public void ReduceSec()
    {
        Sec--;
        if (Sec <= 0)
        {
           Min--;
        }

        if (Min <= 0)
        {
            Rounds++;
        }

        if (Rounds >= MaxRounds)
        {
            Min = oMin;
            Sec = oSec;
            Rounds++;
        }
    }
}
```